# Insert data from Listbox to table

Tags: vba, ms-access

Can you guys please help on the following code

As an attached Invoice form screenshot, I'm trying to Insert the data from Listbox to the table with a loop, but it is not working. Please check the below VBA and let me know where I'm going wrong.

```
Private Sub btn_Save_Click()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To ItemsListBox.ListCount - 1 Step 1
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblSE_B(Inv_No,Item_ID,Qty,LP,MRP,GST,IGST,C_Dsic,LPR_Total,R_Total) VALUES('" & txtInvNo & "','" & ItemsListBox.Column(0, i) & "','" & ItemsListBox.Column(1, i) & "','" & ItemsListBox.Column(2, i) & "','" & ItemsListBox.Column(3, i) & "','" & ItemsListBox.Column(4, i) & "','" & ItemsListBox.Column(5, i) & "','" & ItemsListBox.Column(6, i) & "','" & ItemsListBox.Column(8, i) & "','" & ItemsListBox.Column(9, i) & "')"
      Next i
      MsgBox "Successfully done", vbInformation, "Sales"

End Sub
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Hi @Sandhya, #1. would you please show the Tables Structure on your Question as well please for us to investigate better on why your operation is not working?

Comment: #2. Also if you could update the Question: **What is the error message**

Comment: Hi Siriniaina,

I'm sharing my database, please open the form of frmSE

Comment: Hi @Sandhya, I posted an answer for you below now. Kindly read the Remark I gave you why your Query were failing and you may try the solution. But do not forget to remove the Comments as they are only to help you and are not accepted by VBA Access!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your mistake is this:

> ---> You were mixing **Text (Needs Apostrophy Text Marker ['] before and after)** and **Numeric (No need of ['] before and after)** in your Sql:

---

> **UPDATE**:

```
'Qty: Number 
'LP: Number 
'MRP: Number 
'C_Disc: Number 
'GST: Number 
'IGST: Number 
'LPR_Total: Number 
'R_Total: Number    

Private Sub btn_Save_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim Sql As String

    For i = 0 To ItemsListBox.ListCount - 1 Step 1
        Sql = "INSERT INTO tblSE_B( Inv_No, " & _
                                   "Item_ID," & _
                                   "Qty," & _
                                   "LP, " & _
                                   "MRP," & _
                                   "GST," & _
                                   "IGST," & _
                                   "C_Disc," & _
                                   "LPR_Total," & _
                                   "R_Total)" & _
                " VALUES('" & txtInvNo & "','" & _              
                            ItemsListBox.Column(0, i) & "'," & _
                            ItemsListBox.Column(1, i) & "," & _ 
                            ItemsListBox.Column(2, i) & "," & _ 
                            ItemsListBox.Column(3, i) & "," & _ 
                            ItemsListBox.Column(4, i) & "," & _ 
                            ItemsListBox.Column(5, i) & "," & _ 
                            ItemsListBox.Column(6, i) & "," & _ 
                            ItemsListBox.Column(8, i) & "," & _ 
                            ItemsListBox.Column(9, i) & ");"
            CurrentDb.Execute Sql

    Next i
          MsgBox "Successfully done", vbInformation, "Sales"

End Sub
```

> > So `Item_ID is now Text` then I had to put back the ('). So, kindly use this script now.

### Debug the Sql Query:

Now here is what you need to do:

1. Put a Breakpoint on `CurrentDb.Execute Sql`
2. Get the Value of `Sql` from your **Immediate window** or from your **Local Variable Window**
3. Copy in your Clipboard the `Sql` text
4. Open your **Database**
5. Try to create **a New Query** based on the `Sql Script` you have in your Clipboard.
6. Test if the Insert went successfully.
7. If it goes then the issue is in your VBA. If not, then the Script has an issue.
8. Kindly update your Question with the new Error and we can see how to solve it!

Hope this will help you!

Comment: @SandhyaSS, kindly to not forget to Vote and Accept the answer when it is working for you. Thank you very much. Blessings :)

Comment: I just tried it same as in the above code block. I removed ( ' ) for all number fields and keep it for 1st two text inputs, finally not working.

Comment: The following fields are my table fields & datatypes.

ID: AutoNumber
Inv_No: Short Text
Item_ID: Number
Qty: Number
LP: Number
MRP: Number
C_Disc: Number
GST: Number
IGST: Number
LPR_Total: Number
R_Total: Number

Comment: Kindly try this now and let me know when it is Working!

Comment: Kindly please check the below posted code. I did try like that, but still, it is not working. :(

Comment: @SandhyaSS, I updated the script and the answer. Kindly try the solution I just gave you and follow scrupulously the steps and show the error on your Question again.

Comment: Ok, I will try and let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212187/discussion-between-sandhya-ss-and-tsiriniaina-rakotonirina).

Comment: Please come to chat.

Comment: Hi @SandhyaSS, kindly Accept the Answer since it's already solve to help others as well. Blessings!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that some of the data that you are trying to insert is numeric, so there is no need to wrap the values in single quotes. For example, if all of the values are numeric then you would use this inside the loop:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblSE_B(Inv_No,Item_ID,Qty,LP,MRP,GST,IGST,C_Dsic,LPR_Total,R_Total) VALUES(" & txtInvNo & "," & ItemsListBox.Column(0, i) & "," & ItemsListBox.Column(1, i) & "," & ItemsListBox.Column(2, i) & "," & ItemsListBox.Column(3, i) & "," & ItemsListBox.Column(4, i) & "," & ItemsListBox.Column(5, i) & "," & ItemsListBox.Column(6, i) & "," & ItemsListBox.Column(8, i) & "," & ItemsListBox.Column(9, i) & ")"
```

It also may not be good database practice to store all of these fields when you may be OK with just the ID field, but without knowing what you are doing and why, it is difficult to say for certain.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 1st 2 fields are text inputs, remaining all are numeric values.